# Why JSON does not need setXXX method?

Tags: java, json, jackson

As question mention, I am very curious, why when the deserialization happen, it does not need setter for the fields? Only getter is needed?

I am using Jackson's JSON.

Comment: Did you read their documentation? Maybe they set the value directly by using reflection.

Comment: Indeed, reflection is used under the hood, either using setter method (if available) or field (if not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackson, and similar Java-to/from-JSON tools, don't even need a getter to set/modify a field value.  The field to be set/modified could even be private and final (with a value already specified -- Jackson won't necessarily respect the immutability of a field).  How is this possible?  As Thomas suggested, Jackson can use reflection to set field values.  This behavior is described at http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_409.html.